# BeautifulSoup child-tags and removing duplicates

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm attempting to clean some html by parsing it through BeautifulSoup using Python 2.

BeautifulSoup parses the `raw_html` which is associated with a `website_id` in the `html_dict`. It also removes any attribute associated with the html tags (`<a>, <b>`, and `<p>`).

```
html_dict = {"l0000": ["<a href='some url'>test</a>", "lol", "<a><b>test</b></a>"], "l0001":["<p>this is html</p>", "<p>this is html</p>"]}

clean_html = {}

for website_id, raw_html in html_dict.items():
    for i in raw_html:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(i, 'html.parser')
        scrape_selected_tags = soup.find_all(["a", "b", "p"])

# Remove attributes from html tag

        for i in scrape_selected_tags:
            i.attrs = {}

        print website_id, scrape_selected_tags
```

This outputs:

```
l0001 [<p>this is html</p>]
l0001 [<p>this is html</p>]
l0000 [<a>test</a>]
l0000 []
l0000 [<a><b>test</b></a>, <b>test</b>]
```

I have two questions:

1) The last output has outputted "test" twice. I assume this is because it is surrounded by both the `<a>` and `<b>` tags? How does one deal with child-tags to output `<a><b>test</b></a>` only?

2) Given a unique `website_id`, how would one remove duplicates, so that there's only one occurrence of `<p>this is html</p>` for `l0001`? I know that `scrape_selected_tags` has a type of `bs4.element.ResultSet` and I'm not sure how to handle this and insert the new output in the same format as `html_dict` but in `clean_html`.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Set the [`recursive`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#the-recursive-argument) argument to `False`. This will select only direct descendants and will not go deeper in the soup. The problem with this method is that children tags will hold their attributes, so you'll have to use one more loop to clean them.

2) Use a set (or you could use list comprehensions) to select only unique tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html_dict = {
    "l0000":["<a href='some url'>test</a>", "lol", "<a class='1'><b class='2'>test</b></a>"], 
    "l0001":["<p>this is html</p>", "<p>this is html</p>"]
}
clean_html = {}

for website_id, raw_html in html_dict.items():
    clean_html[website_id] = []
    for i in raw_html:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(i, 'html.parser')
        scrape_selected_tags = soup.find_all(["a", "b", "p"], recursive=False)

        for i in scrape_selected_tags:
            i.attrs = {}
        for i in [c for p in scrape_selected_tags for c in p.find_all()]:
            i.attrs = {}
        clean_tags = list(set(scrape_selected_tags + clean_html[website_id]))
        clean_html[website_id] = clean_tags

print(clean_html)
```

---

```
{'l0001': [<p>this is html</p>], 'l0000': [<a><b>test</b></a>, <a>test</a>]}
```

Comment: This is great, however, what if there are more than 2 nested tags? I can't really rely on looping like this when I might not know how many child tags there are, or does this not make a difference?